# Ext JS Image in Viewport

Tags: extjs

I need some help in inserting an image in 'north' panel of Viewport.

The prob is, upon page load, size of north region is set to default: 20px. As a result, only some portion of image is visible. I want it to be adjusted as per the image height.

But as I click on split panels, it adjusts as per the size of image (seems some rendering problem at load?)

following is the ext js code.. Using Ext Js 5.0

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'border',

    items: [
    {
        region: 'north',
        html: '<img src="..." alt="" />',
        border: false,
        margin: '0 0 0 0',
    },{
        region: 'center',
        xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
        activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
        items: {
            title: 'Contents',
            html: 'The first tab\'s content. Others may be added dynamically'
        }
    }
    ]
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First problem is that when you use border layout, few items are required:

1. Any Container using the Border layout must have a child item with region:'center'. The child item in the center region will always be resized to fill the remaining space not used by the other regions in the layout.
2. Any child items with a region of west or east may be configured with either an initial width, or a Ext.layout.container.Box.flex value, or an initial percentage width string (Which is simply divided by 100 and used as a flex value). The 'center' region has a flex value of 1.
3. Any child items with a region of north or south may be configured with either an initial height, or a Ext.layout.container.Box.flex value, or an initial percentage height string (Which is simply divided by 100 and used as a flex value). The 'center' region has a flex value of 1.

See the doc for more info.

So I would change your panel to `hbox`, set the main container with `flex: 1` and add some logic to make sure that when you load the images the container's layout is updated to fix it's height.

Code below, hope it helps:

```
Ext.create('Ext.container.Viewport', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    layout: 'vbox',

    items: [
        {
            border: false,
            margin: '0 0 0 0',
            items : [{
               xtype : 'image',
               src : 'http://cdn.sencha.io/img/touch2/Sencha-SDK-Tools-icon.png',
               listeners : {
                    boxready : function (component) {
                        component.getEl().on('load', function(){
                            component.ownerCt.updateLayout();
                        });
                    }
                }
            }],
            layout: {
                type: 'anchor'
            }
        },{
            flex: 1,
            xtype: 'tabpanel', // TabPanel itself has no title
            activeTab: 0,      // First tab active by default
            items: {
                title: 'Contents',
                html: 'The first tab\'s content. Others may be added dynamically'
            }
         }
    ]
});
```